# Bug in malloc or mine?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Is this my bug or a bug/assertion fail in `malloc` itself?

> alloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *)
>   &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct
>   malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size)
>
> > = (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t)))
> >     - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.

- libstdc++6:amd64                               4.7.2-2ubuntu1
- gcc 4.7.2
- ubuntu 12.10/64bit

Comment: Its very likely to be a bug in your code, caused by a memory obver-write.  Can you narrow it down to a small enough code sample to post more info?

Comment: You have corrupted the heap somewhere.  `malloc()` is one of the most used functions in the C library, it's unlikely you've stumbled on a bug. See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html and http://blog.regehr.org/archives/26

Comment: Sounds like a job for [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Blaming a bug on malloc is a bit like blaming the compiler. Yes, bugs are sometimes discovered in both. But most of the time when you think you've found a bug in malloc, it actually just means you don't understand your own code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that there's a memory bug in your program (writing to freed memory, buffer overrun, etc). An outright bug in `malloc()` is far less likely.

Comment: Oh, yes, it's perfectly possible.

Comment: @Martin Possible yes, probable no.

Comment: @Martin - If you're using your own custom memory manager (perhaps tuned for certain platform characteristics or embedded system use), I agree that it's very possible.  If you're using GCC+libstdc's memory manager, much less likely.  I work with a guy who was a TA for Purdue's CEE department, and he was always getting students coming in with "proof" that they found a bug in the compiler or runtime.  My co-worker would help them comb through their code (or helped them use valgrind on it).  And never once did they ever actually find such a compiler/runtime bug.